# How to See Only the Image of Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, chart.js

Below is a code which generates an image of a chart after the chart itself has been generated. 
I want to see only the image. Is that possible?

I tried `display: none;` for chart's div but image also doesn't seem.

```
$(function() {

  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
              data: {
              labels: ["July","August","September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April"],
              datasets: [
                  {
                      label: 'This year',
                      data: [340,0,450,3240,360,200,0,0,1445,350],
                  }
                  , {
                      label: 'Last year',
                      data: [330,340,100,160,560,3600,320,0,397.5,300],
                  }
              ]
          },

          options: {
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              responsive: true,
              animation: {
                  onComplete: function(animation){
                      document.querySelector('#myChart').setAttribute('href', this.toBase64Image());
                      document.querySelector('#myImage').setAttribute('src', this.toBase64Image());
                  }
              }
          }
      });

})
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: I tried but there was no result.  Anyway, @naren-murali has posted to fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the question, I created a fiddle. I am removing the chart using the below line.

```
              animation: { 
                    duration: 0,
                  onComplete: function(animation){
                      document.querySelector('#myChart').remove();
                      document.querySelector('#myImage').setAttribute('src', this.toBase64Image());
                  }
              }
```

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/yd9cfvwg/7/)

Comment: Thank you for your time. Chart itself occupy space for sometime before removed. Can you prevent this?

Comment: do you want it like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/yd9cfvwg/3/, the chart takes a bit of time to render.

Comment: This is definitely the accepted answer. Thank you so much again. For improve the answer, is there any way to decrease time to render?

Comment: @erayaras Check my updated answer, the fiddle is also updated.